# Prevent more than one session from overwriting each other on the same website in PHP

Tags: php

I need more light concerning sessions in PHP, when i have two different users logged in on a particular site lets say for instance their dashboard or account (e.g: https://www.myspace.com/admin/dashboard) in separate tabs in the same browser, one session tends to overwrite the other session, how can i prevent this from occurring.

Comment: How can 2 users use the same computer, same browser, visiting same website at the same time in 2 different tabs? I think this a situation that you should not bother yourself with at the server side

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Sessions are identified using session cookies and a single browser instance will share cookies across tabs (with the exception of Incognito/Private/etc).

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yep, ask them to use different computers, different browsers on the same computer, or use it one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I could come up with is by using the fact that you can tell the browser to use a cookie only at specific location.

```
//when user1 visits, set custom session cookie works on his private url
setcookie("sessionId", $sessionTocken1, time() + 3600, "/dashboard/user1"); 

//when user2 visits, set custom session cookie works on his private url
setcookie("sessionId", $sessionTocken2, time() + 3600, "/dashboard/user2");
```

Now user1 on his dashboard at `/dashboard/user1` will send different cookie value than user2 on his dashboard at `/dashboard/user2`

Please note that by doing this you will have to manage a custom session system at the server side rather than the PHP's `$_SESSION` builtin one.

I will not doing this for it's weirdness and complex side effects, I just wrote it in case you really need it. Sessions are built on cookies and cookies are not designed to be working for 2 different users using the same browser at the same time.